# modelMap.put() v/s modelMap.addAttribute()

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In spring, what is the difference between

```
modelMap.put("key",value);
```

and

```
modelMap.addAttribute("Key",value);
```

Answer (score 5):

addAttributes implies check for not null in attribute name -> see sources

```
 /**
     * Add the supplied attribute under the supplied name.
     * @param attributeName the name of the model attribute (never <code>null</code>)
     * @param attributeValue the model attribute value (can be <code>null</code>)
     */
    public ModelMap addAttribute(String attributeName, Object attributeValue) {
        Assert.notNull(attributeName, "Model attribute name must not be null");
        put(attributeName, attributeValue);
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
addAttribute(String attributeName, Object attributeValue)
```

> Add the supplied attribute under the supplied name.

```
put(String attributeName, Object attributeValue)
```

> Associates the specified value with the specified attributeName in
>   this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the
>   attributeName, the old value is replaced.
>
> addAttribute is for adding value and put is for add or replace
>
> If we consider about Java Spring API
>
> java.lang.Object
>       java.util.AbstractMap
>          java.util.HashMap
>            java.util.LinkedHashMap
>                org.springframework.ui.ModelMap
>
> Spring Framework has been inherited from HashMap and put is a method
>   inherited form HashMap.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html

Comment: This is not correct, if you check the implemenation you would see that the two methods are identical except that addattribute checks for null.